# Laravel - Passing id as parameter but the route gets the key, not the value

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So I am experiencing a really strange problem. I am passing my parameters like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('deleteCustomerCartItem', ['product_id', $cartItem['product']->id, 'size' => $cartItem['size']]) }}" method="post">
```

I am printing the `$cartItem['product']->id` inside my cart page and it prints the valid id. However when I pass it and `var_dump` it, I get string(10) "product_id". I noticed that my route doesn't get the actual id but it gets 'product_id'. Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/cart/delete/{product_id}/{size?}', [
'uses' => 'CartController@deleteCustomerItem',
'as' => 'deleteCustomerCartItem']);
```

Here is the url I get from this route:
[image]

product_id must be 1 and S is the `$cartItem['size']`. I don't know why this happens or why it gets '?1' at the end.

I need to get the value of product_id not the key. Can someone explain why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
['product_id' => $cartItem['product']->id, 'size' => $cartItem['size']]

              ^
              |
// Note the use of => here instead of ,
```

Comment: I didn't notice I used commas. Thanks!

Comment: Ben is right, by using a comma you're actually creating an array of two elements. The first element is the string name of the key, and the second is the value you want. The framework was taking that first element.